# Using Printf.printf with Uint64.uint64 Type OCAML

Tags: ocaml

I installed the UInt64 package using OPAM . I wanted to know how I can print an UInt64 type to the screen. I tried doing

```
let someVal = Uint64.of_string "0xcbf39ce214111325"
 Printf.printf "%u" someVal;
```

This is the error that I get

```
This expression has type Uint64.uint64 ref
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Comment: Apparently you guys are in the same class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686156/how-to-get-a-binary-representation-of-uint64-in-ocaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"%u"` specifies an `int` argument. Looking at the `Uint64` interface, you probably want to print by converting to a string: `printf "%s" (Uint64.to_string ...)`.