# How to get a binary representation of Uint64 in OCAML

Tags: ocaml

Suppose I have this

```
let var = Uint64.of_string "0x15E" ;;
```

How do I convert the above no. to get a binary string which would be

```
0b101011110
```

Are there any libraries that would assist in this ?
Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: The language is ocaml

Comment: I'm not familiar with OCaml, but you can get the binary representation of a number very easily. Continuously divide by 2 and take the remainder. This will produce the bits of the number from least significant bit to most significant bit. Since your number has 64 bits, you'd break after the 64th iteration, or when your quotient is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `uint` module from OPAM.

The `uint` module has a function named `Uint64.to_string_bin` that sounds like it does what you want. I don't have the module installed at the moment, so I can't try it.

Comment: Yep that did it. The binary string gets out.